# Cast a TInterfacedObject to an interface

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-2007

[According to the Delphi docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Using_the_as_Operator_with_Interfaces), I can cast a `TInterfacedObject` to an interface using the `as` operator.

But it doesn't work for me. The cast gives a compile error: "Operator not applicable to this operand type".

I'm using Delphi 2007.

Here is some code (a console app). The line that contains the error is marked.

```
program Project6;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  IMyInterface = interface
    procedure Foo;
  end;

  TMyInterfacedObject = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
  public
    procedure Foo;
  end;

procedure TMyInterfacedObject.Foo;
begin
  ;
end;

var
  o: TInterfacedObject;
  i: IMyInterface;
begin
  try
    o := TMyInterfacedObject.Create;
    i := o as IMyInterface;  // <--- [DCC Error] Project6.dpr(30): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Is the docwiki correct? First sentence in the linked page is "Classes that implement interfaces can use the as operator for dynamic binding on the interface.".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Quick answer

Your interface needs to have a GUID for the `as` operator to work. Go to the first line after `IMyInterface = interface`, before any method definitions and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to generate a new GUID.

#### Longer comment

The `as` operator for interfaces requires a GUID because it calls `IUnknown.QueryInterface`, and that in turn requires a GUID. That's all right if you run into this problem when casting an INTERFACE to an other kind of INTERFACE.

You're not supposed to cast an `TInterfacedObject` to an interface in the first place, because that means you're holding both a reference to the implementing object (`TInterfacedObject`) and a reference to the implemented interface (`IMyInterface`). That's problematic because you're mixing two lifecycle management concepts: `TObject` live until something calls `.Free` on them; You're reasonably sure nothing calls `.Free` on your objects without your knowledge. But interfaces are reference-counted: when you assign your interface to a variable the reference counter increases, when that instance runs out of scope (or is assigned something else) the reference counter is decreases. When the reference counter hits ZERO the object is disposed of (`.Free`)!

Here's some innocent-looking code that's going to get into a real lot of trouble fast:

```
procedure DoSomething(If: IMyInterface);
begin
end;

procedure Test;
var O: TMyObjectImplementingTheInterface;
begin
  O := TMyObjectImplementingTheInterface.Create;
  DoSomething(O); // Works, becuase TMyObject[...] is implementing the given interface
  O.Free; // Will likely AV because O has been disposed of when returning from `DoSomething`!
end;
```

The fix is very simple: Change the `O`'s type from `TMyObject[...]` to `IMyInterface`, like this:

```
procedure DoSomething(If: IMyInterface);
begin
end;

procedure Test;
var O: IMyInterface;
begin
  O := TMyObjectImplementingTheInterface.Create;
  DoSomething(O); // Works, becuase TMyObject[...] is implementing the given interface
end; // `O` gets freed here, no need to do it manually, because `O` runs out of scope, decreases the ref count and hits zero.
```

Comment: @David, thanks for fixing my typos. And sorry for the typos themselves, I'm often relying on Opera's spelling-checker, but some errors still get through :( especially words that (to me) are homonyms, because Opera doesn't mark them as miss-spelled and I honestly don't notice them. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the As or Supports operator you need to add a Guid to the Interface, example:

```
type   
  IMyInterface = interface
    ['{00000115-0000-0000-C000-000000000049}']
    procedure Foo;   
  end;
```

See the [docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Object_Interfaces#Interface_Identification_and_GUIDs)

Comment: Oh yes. The joy of copy-pasting code samples! Google that GUID you provided, apparently lots of people thought it's a good idea to just copy paste code!

Comment: Yes it's copied, it's copied from the docwiki I linked to. I don't see the problem with that since the OP should generate a unique GUID anyway...

Comment: Actually, @Cosmin, from the Google results I get, it looks like everyone has copied the *entire Delphi Language Guide*, not just that GUID.

Answer (score 0):

The cast will be automatic of you define the object o as the correct type. Otherwise, you can always use `supports()` and/or call `QueryInterface` yourself.

```
var
  o: TMyInterfacedObject;
  i: IMyInterface;
begin
  try
    o := TMyInterfacedObject.Create;
    i := o;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Both `Supports()` and `QueryInterface()` require a GUID. If the `as` operator is not working, those two variants aren't going to work either.

Comment: QCosmin: yes, you are correct. I always define my interfaces with a GUID so I did not notice...

Comment: You're still holding both references, read @David's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448013/cast-a-tinterfacedobject-to-an-interface/5448191#5448191) to this same question.